# weird csv output using python

Tags: python, csv, screen-scraping

I've recently tried to scrape a http://quotes.toscrape.com/ quotes (only on a first page) and save them into a csv file. I got a pretty weird result. Only commas were used as separators. See screenshot and code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import csv

csvfile = open('quotes.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
writer.writerow(('text'))


def parse():
    html = urlopen('http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/')
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    quotes = bs.findAll('div', class_='quote')
    for quote in quotes:
        try:
            text = quote.find('span', class_='text').getText(
            ).replace(',', '|').replace('"', '')
            print(text)
            writer.writerow((text))
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            break

parse()
csvfile.close()
```

[image: Here it is]

Comment: Define 'weird result'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've attempted to use write rows with a tuple, however (weird quirk) you're not actually using a tuple.

See my example:

```
some_num = (1)
some_tuple = (1,)
```

Change this line:

```
        writer.writerow((text))
```

to

```
        writer.writerow((text,))
```

Note the comma :)

**But why did that happen?**

Rather than breaking it iterated through the string as if it was a tuple of single chars, e.g.

```
>>> for character in "this string":
...     print(character)
t
h
i
s

s
t
r
i
n
g
```